# Prerequisites to understanding proof of Fubini's Theorem?

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, proof-writing

I'm currently studying tensor analysis, and I have studied elementary calculus (meaning calc I, II, III, and diffy Q), as well as linear algebra. Given all of this, what are the rest of the required prerequisites to understand the proof of Fubini's theorem or to be able to prove it myself?